# How to install round brake pads

Tags: disc-brake, brake-pads

I decided to change my bike's brake pads myself. My bike has the following brakes: [Promax DSK-915](http://www.promaxcomponents.com/product/solve-disc-brake/). I contacted the online shop I ordered my new brake pads (and my bike last year), before purchasing, and they told me that these are suitable for my bike: [Cox DBP-06.87-R Disc Brake Pads](http://coxcomponents.com/en/products/details/648).

I got them today, but I have no idea how to put them on my bike, as the old ones I have are not rounded and have little hole that's used to put them in place.

Below you can see my old brakes. The "thing" (split pin/cotter pin) I circled in red goes in the little holes I marked with numbers.

[image: My Old brakes]

I don't understand how I can install my new ones on my brakes:

[image]

Is that even possible? Or the online shop suggested I buy the wrong product? I am so confused.

Comment: The "circled thing" is a split pin (UK usage) or cotter pin (US usage).

Comment: @DavidRicherby Thank you! In Bulgarian it is "фиксиращ шпленд", I tried "google translating" it and it gave me: "fixing pin" as a result. Didn't know whether it is the right term, so I included a picture.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You got the wrong pads.

While it's possible to mix and match *some* pads, this is usually not the case. When replacing pads, keep track of:

1. Pad material and what your rotor is compatible of. Some rotors have a "resin pads only" etched on. Consult user manual or manufacturer website for this info.
2. Pad shape. Note the features, like "handles" shape, amount and location of holes and protrusions.

The pad you want has is called DBP-01.23R. It's a Shimano-compatible (B01S analogue), very wide spread model, you should be able to source a pair from any half-decent bike shop. The round pads are for Promax Render and Decipher and won't work with your Solve.

Answer (score 9):

Well, those are the wrong pads, there’s no way for them to work with your brakes. There are quite a few designs out there, but they need to match.

Fortunately, it sounds like you contacted the retailer for sales advice before the purchase, so I’d say it’s on the retailer to correct their mistake and make sure you aren’t out of pocket. You should contact them and explain the problem, those photos will help explain the situation.

Edit: the brake product page linked mentions Shimano Deore brake pad compatibility. That’s the style you need to source, but there are lots of other brands that make compatible pads.